# Is there a way to extend grid lines over key in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Here's my graph:
[image: Example plot]
The grid lines are not drawn over the key, and the result is somewhat ugly. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance.
(I'm using Gnuplot v4.6.4)

Comment: Maybe `set grid xtics front` ?

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: a workaround would be to use `set arrow from x,y_min to x,y_max nohead` to "fake" the lines - here, `x` denotes the `x`-coordinate where to place the line and `y_min`/`y_max` specify the corresponding `y`-range...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gnuplot will not draw the grid over the area of the key. But you can cheat by reducing the size of this area with something like this (play with the number):

```
set key width -20
```

You might also consider moving the key somewhere else, please read the documentation of `set key` for this purpose.